# Can a 3NF table have a PK with repeating values but all nonkeys are dependent on the PK (no transitive dependency)?

Tags: database, primary-key, 3nf

I know that PK have to have unique values. I also know that for a table to be in 3NF, there can be no non-key depending on another non-key.

I'm trying to create a table with these requirements: The data reflect that a professor can have multiple advisees, can serve on multiple committees, and can edit more than one journal.

I have a Professor table with these attributes (all dependent on PK):

- EMP_NUM (FK) (PK)
- PROF_RANK
- PROF_OFFICE
- COMMITTEE_CODE (FK)
- JOURNAL_CODE (FK)
- ADVISEE_CODE (FK)

Professor A has 5 COMMITTEE_CODE, so I put different COMMITTEE_CODE on different rows (to make each box atomic), but that means I'll have to repeat the EMP_NUM, PROF_RANK and PROF_OFFICE 5 times. So now idk if EMP_NUM can be considered the PK anymore.

I saw examples on some websites that have repeating values for the PK in a 3NF table. But idk, isn't PK supposed to have only unique values?

If I separate the EMP_NUM and COMMITTEE_CODE to a new table, I'll still have to repeat the same EMP_NUM 5 times for 5 different COMMITTEE_CODE.

Comment: I don't know anything about 3NF, but you surely need put relations of professors and committees into separate table (entity) with two FKs. And why do you have both FK and PK attributes on EMP_NUM fields? Does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Arvo I tried putting professors n committees into a separate table, each with a unique code as the PK, but when I connect it to the professor table, I still have to repeat the EMP_NUM anyway. As for the FK PK, I saw another question here that says yes, I can have FK acting as PK (supertyping tables)

Comment: @Arvo is correct that these belong in a separate table. As you have pointed-out, this would mean that the associative entity between Emp & Committee contains emp_num repeated for each committee_code. In this case, the PK for the associative table is a composite of its two FKs.

Comment: About FK+PK on EMP_NUM, does this mean that there is some separate employee table, where EMP_NUM is PK? Sorry I look at this as SQL guy with less theoretical, but more practical history - and I just want to understand your model better :)

Comment: @Arvo yes there is a separate employee table with EMP_NUM as PK. I didn't include it here bcs I didn't think that was relevant to the question. Thanks for your answer btw :)

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & you have shown no research effort. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following a textbook with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. Quote the definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS CKs matter, not PKs; that isn't a definition of 3NF; "repeating" is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand Professor-Commitee is a many-to-many relation. In this case you should create a join table `PROF_COMM_REL` table where it would have

```
SURROGATE ID
EMP_NUM (FK)
COMMITTEE_CODE(FK)
```

The Professor table should not have any `COMMITTEE_CODE` as the relation is stored in the join table.

I would also recommend using surrogate keys - ids that do not have any meaning like anything that can change over time. For example, the name must not be PK as the name of a person can change and it would implicate to update whole db structure

Comment: Normalization to higher NFs does not introduce new columns. Also there is no reason to introduce an id column anyway. Also there are other problems with the question's design. Also this proposes a new design but doesn't justify anything in terms of 3NF or normalziation.